# Base56 conversion etc

Tags: python, encoding

It seems base58 and base56 conversion treat input data as a single Big Endian number; an unsigned bigint number.

If I'm encoding some integers into shorter strings by trying to use base58 or base56 it seems in some implementations the integer is taken as a native (little endian in my case) representation of bytes and then converted to a string, while in other implementations the number is converted to big endian representation first. It seems the loose specifications of these encoding don't clarify which approach is right. Is there an explicit specification of which to do, or a more wildly popular option of the two I'm not aware of?

I was trying to compare some methods of making a short URL. The source is actually a 10 digit number that's less than 4 billion. In this case I was thinking to make it an unsigned 4 byte integer, possibly Little Endian, and then encode it with a few options (with alphabets):

- base64 `A…Za…z0…9+/`
- base64 url-safe `A…Za…z0…9-_`
- Z85 `0…9a…zA…Z.-:+=^!/*?&<>()[]{}@%$#`
- base58 `1…9A…HJ…NP…Za…km…z` (excluding `0IOl+/` from base64 & reordered)
- base56 `2…9A…HJ…NP…Za…kmnp…z` (excluding `1o` from base58)

So like, base16, base32 and base64 make pretty good sense in that they're taking 4, 5 or 6 bits of input data at a time and looking them up in an alphabet index. The latter uses 4 symbols per 3 bytes. Straightforward, and this works for any data.

The other 3 have me finding various implementations that disagree with each other as to the right output. The problem appears to be that no amount of bytes has a fixed number of lookups in these. EG taking 2^1 to 2^100 and getting the remainders for 56, 58 and 85 results in no remainders of 0.

Z85 (ascii85 and base85 etal.) approach this by grabbing 4 bytes at a time and encoding them to 5 symbols and accepting some waste. But there's byte alignment to some degree here (base64 has alignment per 16 symbols, Z85 gets there with 5). But the alphabet is … not great for urls, command-line, nor sgml/xml use.

base58 and base56 seem intent on treating the input bytes like a Big Endian ordered `bigint` and repeating: `% base`; lookup; `-= % base`; `/= base` on the input `bigint`. Which… I mean, I think that ends up modifying most of the input for every iteration.

For my input that's not a huge performance concern though.

Because we shouldn't treat the input as string data, or we get output longer than the 10 digit decimal number input and what's the point in that, *does anyone know of any indication of which kind of processing for the output results in something canonical for base56 or base58*?

1. Have the Little Endian 4 byte word of the 10 digit number (<4*10^10) turned into a sequence of bytes that represent a different number if Big Endian, and convert that by repeating the steps.
2. Have the 10 digit number (<4*10^10) represented in 4 bytes Big Endian before converting that by repeating the steps.

I'm leaning towards going the route of the 2nd way.

For example given the number: 3003295320
The little endian representation is `58 a6 02 b3`
The big endian representation is `b3 02 a6 58`, Meaning

base64 gives:

```
>>> base64.b64encode(int.to_bytes(3003295320,4,'little'))
b'WKYCsw=='
>>> base64.b64encode(int.to_bytes(3003295320,4,'big'))
b'swKmWA=='
>>> base64.b64encode('3003295320'.encode('ascii'))
b'MzAwMzI5NTMyMA=='  # Definitely not using this
```

Z85 gives:

```
>>> encode(int.to_bytes(3003295320,4,'little'))
b'sF=ea'
>>> encode(int.to_bytes(3003295320,4,'big'))
b'VJv1a'
>>> encode('003003295320'.encode('ascii'))  # padding to 4 byte boundary
b'fFCppfF+EAh8v0w'  # Definitely not using this
```

base58 gives:

```
>>> base58.b58encode(int.to_bytes(3003295320,4,'little'))
b'3GRfwp'
>>> base58.b58encode(int.to_bytes(3003295320,4,'big'))
b'5aPg4o'
>>> base58.b58encode('3003295320')
b'3soMTaEYSLkS4w'  # Still not using this
```

base56 gives:

```
>>> b56encode(int.to_bytes(3003295320,4,'little'))
b'4HSgyr'
>>> b56encode(int.to_bytes(3003295320,4,'big'))
b'6bQh5q'
>>> b56encode('3003295320')
b'4uqNUbFZTMmT5y'  # Longer than 10 digits so...
```

Comment: if the question is "is there a canonical way of doing this" then I don't think so, just do whatever is most convenient given other constraints in your design.  for your other comments, could you be more explicit about the problem?

Comment: Actually, I think that was the question. Like I'd seen some attempts at a base58 & 56 cli tool that take plain text, and then it behaves differently if that plain text is all digits because it makes it an int. In this case the tool took the int as little endian before proceeding encoding the bytes, but I saw a gist or two where they proceeded with big endian, and so I wondered if there was a far more common one of the two. I think the bitcoin use is big endian, and that might be the most common use (but I'm not sure)